# Oracle SQL: Return string from blob between two strings (probably using REGEXP_SUBSTR)

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I am trying to export data from a blob to use in a report, however I am having trouble using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` when trying to read from it. Converting it to a `varchar` is helping, however getting the data point I need is quite hard as I am finding!

Here is how I am getting it to a varchar:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(NOTE)) FROM prod17import;
```

This is a sample of the output to varchar:

```
"Import: T5, ModId: #24, Time: 1/11/2017 7:32:30 AM
Records read: 1723
Added:  1723, Changed: 0
Rejected: 0, Skipped: 0
0.01 Minutes. 234422 recs/min
Map=IMCOWITHHOLDINGLAYOUTTEST9A.MPWM 
Source=W:\(filename).TXT, created: 1/10/2017 11:15:44 PM

Reject name: REJECT
Resource name: !6Imports.Liability.Maps.Life Import Resource
"
```

I am trying to gather only the value 234422 (which can vary between 1-1,000,000)

How do I get that value between the word "Minutes." and "recs/min"?

Comment: Why BLOB and not CLOB? BLOB is for binary files, not for text. You shouldn't expect it to be easy to extract text from BLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string format is consistent, use

```
select regexp_substr(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(NOTE)) 
                     ,'minutes. ([0-9]+) recs/min',1,1,'i',1)
from prod17import
```

`i` as the argument specifies case-insensitive matching. Use `null` if you need the match to be case-sensitive.